# Upgrading django-cms to 3.1.2 and django to 1.8.3

Tags: django, django-cms

Im trying to upgrade my django-cms project from django-cms 3.1.0 to 3.1.2 and django 1.7.1 to django 1.8.3, but when I run `python manage.py runserver` in terminal I get this error:

```
File "/home/testacc/projects/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/setup.py", line 33, in validate_settings
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("django CMS requires django.template.context_processors.request in "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: django CMS requires django.template.context_processors.request in 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates' context processors.
```

Comment: did you add django.template.context_processors.request to your context processors? (settings) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/

Comment: tried it, but im getting this error now ImportError: No module named doc

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UqKR0j5F

Comment: Why don't you try creating a django-cms blank project and copy over the general settings? It seems to be an issue with a  middleware.

Comment: I have renamed django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware to django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware  in settings.py and its working now.

Answer (score 15):

In Django 1.8 [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS deprecated.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)
Use this in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors':
            (
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
            )
    }
},
]
```